# R Makevars Simple Library Import e.g. fftw3

Tags: c++, r, fftw

I am currently developing an R package with some C/C++ code depending on various external libraries.

- Rcpp
- png
- fopenmp
- fftw3 (Fourier Transform)

I am looking for an easy way to create a Makevars file that users do not need to adjust later (more or less) - also regarding to the upload to CRAN later.
So maybe this enumeration of external libraries can also give a useful example for other users who need similar or the same libraries ;)

So far, in the documentation and other sources I've found the following hints to write the Makevars file:

1. Rcpp: Use `${R_HOME}/bin/Rscript -e "Rcpp:::LdFlags()"` in `PKG_LIBS`
2. png: Use `$(PNG_LIBS) -lpng` in `PKG_LIBS`. But it seems that an empty string is used then.
3. fopenmp: Use `$(SHLIB_OPENMP_CFLAGS)` in `PKG_CXXFLAGS` and `PKG_LIBS` (but this depends if you use C or C++ Code, See *Writing R Extensions, Sec. 1.2.1.1*
4. fftw3: Here I could not find an easy way. Currently, I use `locate fftw3` to get the path to the library. Then, I write it in the Makevars file.

So finally, my makevars file looks like:

```
PKG_CXXFLAGS= $(SHLIB_OPENMP_CFLAGS)
PKG_LIBS= -L/usr/local/lib -lm -lfftw3f $(PNG_LIBS) -lpng 
           $(SHLIB_OPENMP_CFLAGS) `${R_HOME}/bin/Rscript -e "Rcpp:::LdFlags()"`
```

The question is, if this file is actually correct? I works fine for me, but I cannot judge if it will work for other users?
Do I really need a configure script to find the fftw3 library?

Moreover, is it allowed to upload an R package to CRAN where the user has to adjust the makevars file?